# How to use multiple proxy when crawling with scrapy + splash?

Tags: proxy, scrapy, scrapy-splash

We crawl with scrapy + splash and we want to use multiple proxy. But splash only support single proxy https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#proxy-profiles.

```
[proxy]

; required
host=proxy.crawlera.com
port=8010

; optional, default is no auth
username=username
password=password

; optional, default is HTTP. Allowed values are HTTP and SOCKS5
type=HTTP
```

**How to use multiple proxy when crawling with scrapy + splash?**

Comment: What do you mean by "only supports a single proxy"? That's not true, you can create various profiles with different proxies and for each request you can tell the crawler which profile you want to use making the crawler use a different process

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

- use multiple profiles (as Rafael Almeida suggested in comment);
- pass a different proxy URL with each request (see http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#arg-proxy);
- write a Splash Lua script and use [request:set_proxy](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-request-object.html#splash-request-set-proxy) in [splash:on_request](http://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html#splash-on-request) callback - there is an example in docs. This way you can set a different proxy for different requests initialted by a page, not only a single proxy per rendered page. I'm not aware of a way to do that in other browser automation tools like phantomjs or selenium.